# Compiler warns about mismatch in processor architecture, while corflags claims otherwise

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, anycpu

The compiler gives the following warning:

> warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor
>   architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor
>   architecture of the reference "NationalInstruments.DAQmx", "x86".

When I check the DLL(s) that I use from national intruments, I see that each and every one of them are built against any cpu architecture.

> corflags NationalInstruments.DAQmx.dll
>
> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework CorFlags Conversion Tool.  Version 
>   4.0.30319.1 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Version   : v4.0.30319 
>   CLR Header: 2.5 
>   ** PE        : PE32 **
>   CorFlags  : 24
>   ILONLY    : 0 
>   ** 32BIT     : 0 **
>   Signed    : 1

As I understood PE32 + 32BIT 0 == Any Cpu.

Any advise on how to wrap my head around this would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any CPU is equivalent to PE = PE32, 32Bit = 0, AND ILOnly = 1. Since ILOnly = 0, the assembly contains unmanaged code and cannot be Any CPU. [This](http://programmersnotebook.wordpress.com/2010/02/13/sorting-out-the-confusion-32-vs-64-bit-clr-vs-native-cs-vs-cpp/) blog entry has some interesting further reading on the corflags output.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well! Helpful